# Cannot insert row into table through create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, form-submit

I'm sure there has to be a very simple solution to my problem but i don't know why i cant seem to put my finger on it, the problem is that I'm trying to submit a form but every time i submit the form the create action controller gives the following error

> Mysql2::Error: Column 'preffered_players' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `saved_sessions` (`preffered_players`, `session_id`, `preffered_opponents`, `game_id`, `game_type`, `opponents_list`, `banned_players`, `players_list`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

how ever all these values that the error says are null are passed through parameters as soon as the form is submitted, can anyone tell me how to use the parameter values that i get from the form to fill in the little nulls in my query, create controller is as follow

```
def create
    opponents_list = params[:opponents_list]
    banned_players = params[:banned_players]
    game_type = params[:game_type]
    session_id = params[:session_id]
    preffered_opponents = params[:preffered_opponents]
    game_id = params[:game_id]
    players_list = params[:players_list]
    preffered_players = params[:preffered_players]

    @saved_sessions = SavedSession.new(params[:saved_sessions])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @saved_sessions.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@game, :notice => 'Game was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @game, :status => :created, :location => @game }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @game.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

thanks for any advice...

i'm including the form code however its very messy(its a huge form) plus its in haml :)

```
- form_tag('/saved_sessions',:method => :post, :id => "new_game") do
.select_option
  .list_col1
    .fl
      %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/happy_face.png"}/
    .blue_col
      = text_field_tag :preffered_opponents, "", :class => :blue_bar
    .clr
  .list_col2
    .list_col2_top_row
      .radio_row
        .fl
          %input{:type => "radio", :name => "battle_scale", :value => "3"}
        .fl 3 vs 3
        .fl
          %input{:type => "radio", :name => "battle_scale", :value => "5"}
        .fl 5 vs 5
        .clr
      %div
        .fl
          %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/sad_face.png"}/
        .fl
          /%input#banned_players.white_bar{:type => "text"}/
          = text_field_tag :banned_players, "", :class => :white_bar
        .clr
    .versus_row
      #inputs-vs.versus_col1
        .versus_col_row
          .blue_col
            /%input#input-1-vs.blue_bar{:type => "text"}/
            = text_field_tag 'input-1-vs', "", :class => :blue_bar
          .fl
            %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/lock.png"}/
          .clr
        .versus_col_row
          .blue_col
            /%input#input-2-vs.blue_bar{:type => "text"}/
            = text_field_tag 'input-2-vs', "", :class => :blue_bar
          .fl
            %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/lock.png"}/
          .clr
        .versus_col_row
          .blue_col
            /%input#input-3-vs.blue_bar{:type => "text"}/
            = text_field_tag 'input-3-vs', "", :class => :blue_bar
          .fl
            %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/lock.png"}/
          .clr
        .versus_col_row
          .blue_col
            /%input#input-4-vs.blue_bar{:type => "text"}/
            = text_field_tag 'input-4-vs', "", :class => :blue_bar
          .fl
            %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/lock.png"}/
          .clr
        .versus_col_row
          .blue_col
            /%input#input-5-vs.blue_bar{:type => "text"}/
            = text_field_tag 'input-5-vs', "", :class => :blue_bar
          .fl
            %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/lock.png"}/
          .clr
      .versus_col2
        %img{:alt => "0", :border => "0", :src => "/images/vs.png"}/
      #inputs.versus_col1
        .versus_col_row
          .fl
            %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/lock.png"}/
          .blue_col
            /%input#input-1.pink_bar{:name => "blah", :type => "text"}/
            = text_field_tag 'input-1', "", :class => :pink_bar
          .clr
        .versus_col_row
          .fl
            %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/lock.png"}/
          .blue_col
            /%input#input-2.pink_bar{:name => "blah", :type => "text"}/
            = text_field_tag 'input-2', "", :class => :pink_bar
          .clr
        .versus_col_row
          .fl
            %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/lock.png"}/
          .blue_col
            /%input#input-3.pink_bar{:name => "blah", :type => "text"}/
            = text_field_tag 'input-3', "", :class => :pink_bar
          .clr
        .versus_col_row
          .fl
            %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/lock.png"}/
          .blue_col
            /%input#input-4.pink_bar{:name => "blah", :type => "text"}/
            = text_field_tag 'input-4', "", :class => :pink_bar
          .clr
        .versus_col_row
          .fl
            %img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/lock.png"}/
          .blue_col
            /%input#input-5.pink_bar{:name => "blah", :type => "text"}/
            = text_field_tag 'input-5', "", :class => :pink_bar
          .clr
      .clr
    .session_row
      %p
        %b You can save and share this session by entering your email. A unique code will be sent
      %p.small_text (Session are stored for 30 days)
    .seesion_send_row
      .fl
        /%input.big_white_bar{:type => "text"}/
        = text_field_tag 'email_bar', "", :class => :big_white_bar
      .fl
        %span 2+2=
        %span
        %span
          /%input.small_bar{:type => "text"}/
          = text_field_tag 'code_bar', "", :class => :small_bar
      .fl
        /%a{:href => "#."}
        /%img{:alt => "image", :border => "0", :src => "/images/send_button.png"}/
        = submit_tag("Send")
```

hope this can help you guys better understand the problem..

Comment: Posting your form code would help us to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be pulling from 2 different places. The block of code at the top of the method is pulling the values from the top level of the incoming params, but then later you initialize a new SavedSession using the params[:saved_sessions] input. The two things don't seem to match...

if saved_sessions.opponents_list is found at opponents_list = params[:opponents_list] in the first line, then when you later try to save params[:saved_sessions], you're getting it from a different spot in the params...

EDIT: so you do not need both of the sets of values you have in the action. if you build your form like this (or at least something like this) you'll get the params correctly and can just blindly send them into SavedSession.new, and then call .save.

```
- form_for(@aved_session) do |f| 
  -.blue_col
      = f.text_field :preffered_opponents, "", :class => :blue_bar
```

If you allow f.text_field to build the id and name then rails magic will make sure that they are named/id'd correctly and then more rails magic interprets them and builds your input parameters correctly. This will build your params as:

```
params = {:saved_session => {:preferred_opponents => "text value" }...
```

Then you can pull those params out:

```
saved_session_input = params[:saved_session]
```

and pass them into new just like you are. the difference is that now those parameters are actually IN there.

The way you have it is like this:

```
params = {:preferred_opponents => "text value", :saved_session => {:preferred_opponents => nil }...
```

this means you're passing nil in for the expected values for new. Note that you don't actually assign your local values to the new saved_session before calling save.

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: But i do need both of them don't I, i need the variables(the block on top of the code) so i can store their values into the db and i do need to initialize a new SavedSession using params[:saved_sessions], what am i missing????

Comment: If your form is set up correctly the top block of code should be redundant, I have no experience with HAML, what do the parameters look like in the logs when you hit send

Comment: the problem is that you aren't building your form correctly. By way of example. I'll add an example to my answer to help it make more sense. hold tight a moment or two :)